# samsung note 2 and note 3 screen bucket

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile, android-screen-support, android-screen

What screen bucket do the Samsung Note 2 and Note 3 report?  "Normal" or "Large"?

Here are stats on the two phones:

```
Model   Dimensions            Density     Density Bucket    DP Dimensions
note2   720px x 1280px        265dpi      hdpi              480dp x 853dp
note3   1080px x 1920px       386dpi      xhdpi             540dp x 960dp
```

This post from Diane Hackborn:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

...says that "large" screens are at least 480dp x 640dp, so both these phones would qualify.  What I'd like to know is whether they actually report themselves as having "large" screens or if they self-identify as having "normal" screens.

Unfortunately I don't own either phone so I can't test it out myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Samsung Galaxy Note 2](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/20274/20140121-8bqu-36kb.jpg):
[image: Samsung Galaxy Note 2]

[Samsung Galaxy Note 3](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/20274/20140121-hahl-35kb.jpg):
[image: Samsung Galaxy Note 3]

Comment: Thanks man.  That's strange- those logical densities are wrong, per Google's specs.  I guess that's why they can get away with reporting a screen size of "normal"?  Per Google, hdpi is supposed to be ~240 ppi and xhdpi is supposed to be ~320 ppi.

Comment: I don't know why. It's Samsung and they do what they want) Developers can use different directories of devices parameters to check entire device.

Please, accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Dimmerg where did you get such detailed data, please?

Comment: @anoniim, it's from internal statistics in my Android games