# My android app is not showing up for Galaxy Note 3

Tags: android, google-play, screen-size

Hi I recently published an app to Google Play. My app only support small screen and normal screen and don't support tablets. Here is my manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <compatible-screens>
    <!--all small size screens -->    
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    </compatible-screens>

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />  

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.SplashPage"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
            android:name="com.apps.mmaters.HomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.apps.mmatters.HomeActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>    

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.FullImageActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.MiffyActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.FairyFluActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.FootballFairyActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.HappyHalloweenActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.FGatheringActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.FaqActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.FairyCouncilActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.FGrownActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.GemmaActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.HappyNyActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.WG2014Activity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.WoodlandFairiesActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.apps.mmatters.SpringCleaningActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem I am having is that the app seems to be showing up on most phones except Galaxy Note 3. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

I used a function in my code to check the "category" of the screen size when I was running the app on the Note 3 and result that returned was "Normal". So unless the Note 3 screen is considered to be "Large" then I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Wait it takes time until it appears on all devices.

Answer (score 2):

Note 3 is `screenDensity:xxhdpi` and `screenSize:normal`, so you must add it. 
Also, you must have in mind that:

> The Android system does not read the compatible-screens manifest
>   element (neither at install-time nor at runtime). This element is
>   informational only and may be used by external services

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Comment: I added xxhdpi in but Eclipse is giving me the following error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenDensity' with value 'xxhdpi').

Comment: You better use the constant value for xxhdpi: 480.

Comment: Are you sure it is screenSize:normal? Because the screenSize:large range is from 5" to 7".

Comment: <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" /> Hopefully this will work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265670/samsung-note-2-and-note-3-screen-bucket

Comment: This is why the documentation specifically says "Normally, you should not use this manifest element".