# Android dp units not matching up to real world

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile

I'm testing on a [Samsung Galaxy Note 3](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_3-5665.php) which according to the docs is 1080 x 1920 pixels (~386 ppi pixel density). I want to figure out what the **screen width in dp** is so I can properly apply and check the [new size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers).

I've measured the screen width (in portrait) with a good 'ole ruler **= 71mm = 2.8 inches
1080 / 2.8 = 386 ppi**. Great, this matches the stated density.

I'm trying to figure out how many dp units the screen is wide.

> dp = px / (dpi / 160) from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms)
>   = 1080 / (386 / 160) = 1080 /
>   2.4125 = 447.7 dp

So if I do this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/density_test"
android:layout_width="447dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffff0000"
android:text="DENSITY TEST 447dp" />
```

then on my Galaxy Note 3 this view should be almost exactly the width of the screen. **But it isn't, it's way wider**.

So I set the above view to `layout_width="300dp"`, measured how wide it was with my ruler and extrapolated the actual screen width in dp, based on this test:

> 300dp = 59mm
>
> Total screen width is 71mm
>
> so extrapolating screen width in dp = (71 / 59) * 300 = 361dp

**361dp != 447.7dp**

What is going on here? I feel like I must be doing something dumb.

**Edit:** I tried putting the layout file inside /res/layout-xhdpi but it had no effect. I thought maybe it was scaling it by xhdpi / mdpi since I had the xml in the default /res/layout dir.

[image]

Comment: [Related measurements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265670/samsung-note-2-and-note-3-screen-bucket).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual pixel size is calculated based on dp, but not as accurate as the formula dp = px / (dpi / 160) does. Indeed, it first determines the screen density (ldpp, mdph, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) and using that density to get one ratio from {0.75, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, (4.0)}.

In you case, the system deems 386dpi as xxhdpi, so it calculates the value by multiplying 3.0, and 360dp would exactly fill the width of your screen (1080p)