# Samsung Galaxy Note 3 use normal layout instead of large layout

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile

I have read the question about which layout is used in Samsung galaxy note III.

[samsung note 2 and note 3 screen bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265670/samsung-note-2-and-note-3-screen-bucket)

However, they did not give the reason why the samsung note 3 used normal layout instead of large layout.

I also tried to add the custom device in android studio layout preview, it also showed the large layout would be applied for. I cannot find the reason why it is such strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange behaviour at all. If you read the table you linked carefully, you will see the logical screen size of Galaxy Notes is "normal", hence it will not use layout resources stored into -large directories.

Comment: However, I try to add the custom device with the same definition as note 3 in Android Studio. It showed that it will use the large layout but actually it is not . In the table, the DPI float is 3 but my calculation is ~2.4 but not 3. I cannot find any way how to calculate the "logical screen size" of Galaxy Notes.

Comment: Try using a -sw320dp folder instead of -large, maybe it will work!

Comment: Also, you could find this interesting: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Long Ranger, As per the link you already gave us, Samsung is misreporting its density for the Note 3 as xx-hdpi instead of x-hdpi and as a normal size instead of a large size. It's a mistake on their part, but at least making the mistake on those two variables keeps the equation somewhat balanced. In any case, don't be afraid to fudge the numbers a little when creating AVDs, or to use different phone models when creating your AVDs.  Your layouts will need to work on multiple ranges of devices anyway, not just for the note 3.